# Orchard custom module showing blank "Create" page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, module, orchardcms

I created a custom module for Orchard following [this wonderful guide](http://skywalkersoftwaredevelopment.net/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-1).

I have created a controller called BarberAdminController as follows:

```
[Admin]
public class BarberAdminController : Controller
{
    ...

    public BarberAdminController(IOrchardServices services, IRepository<BarberPart> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _services = services;
    }

    ... 

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var barber = _services.ContentManager.New(typeof(BarberPart).ToString());

        dynamic model = _services.ContentManager.BuildEditor(barber);

        return View(model);
    } 
}
```

View:

```
@{ Layout.Title = T("New Barber").ToString(); }

@using (Html.BeginFormAntiForgeryPost()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    // Model is a Shape, calling Display() so that it is rendered using the most specific template for its Shape type
    @Display(Model)
}
```

Upon clicking the link from the admin menu to create a Barber, I get a blank page with nothing but a "Save" button. (URL: /Admin/BarberShop/Barbers/Create)

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

I've set up the routes and admin links and they seem to work fine. I followed the guide as closely as I could on creating the Drivers and Handlers for BarberPart correctly. Including down to the Migration.cs file database schema.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Missing placement maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I needed to define a Content Part and Content Type for BarberPart. In Migrations.cs, do:

```
ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition(typeof(BarberPart).Name, p => p
            .Attachable(false));
ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("Barber", t => t
            .WithPart(typeof(BarberPart).Name));
```

In the "Create" method of the Controller, replace:

```
var barber = _services.ContentManager.New(typeof(BarberPart).ToString());
```

with:

```
BarberPart barber = _services.ContentManager.New<BarberPart>("Barber");
```

Make sure that you have a Drivers/BarberDriver.cs file as such:

```
public class BarberDriver : ContentPartDriver<BarberPart> 
{
    protected override DriverResult Editor(BarberPart part, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        return ContentShape("Parts_Barber_Edit", () => shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(TemplateName: "Parts/Barber", Model: part, Prefix: Prefix));
    }

    protected override DriverResult Editor(BarberPart part, IUpdateModel updater, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        updater.TryUpdateModel(part, Prefix, null, null);
        return Editor(part, shapeHelper);
    }
}
```

Be sure to have a part edit template located in /Views/EditorTemplates/Parts/Barber.cshtml that looks like this:

```
@model SDKU.Barbr.Models.BarberPart

<fieldset>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SomePropertyName)
    etc...
</fieldset>
```